# Retrieving timestamp of MySQL row creation from meta data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I have been maintaining a MySQL table of rows of data inserted from PHP code for about a year and a half. Really stupid, I know, I didn't include the `timestamp` for insertion of these rows.

Is there any possible way that I can retrieve the `timestamp` of creation of these rows through some metadata or some other way? (Of MySQL or PHPMyAdmin or some other possible ways?)

Comment: the meta-data in mysql is in `information_schema` db and regarding your question you can only see in `TABLES` the create time and update time for a table but nothing regarding each row

Comment: same thing happens to me, I have maintaining the records since two years. At the time I started I really didn't need to maintain record insertion time so I ignored it but now the scenario changed I regret it :(

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do in this case. If MySQL had a secret timestamp field, the general size of tables [would increase by 4 bytes per row](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).

Answer (score 4):

The only way you can get that timestamp, if it is saved somewhere on one of your servers. You have a web server, which you may keep archive of logs for. Or some other place where there is a timestamp of activity of PHP script making requests to the database.

Say you have web server logs and there is an entry for each or most of PHP script activity, then, potentially, you can parse that log, get the timestamp and map it to the rows in your database. As you can see it is quite labourious, but not utterly impossible.

As for MySQL (or any other database) normally they do not keep a big archive of past information. Main reason for that - it is updo developer or designer of the application to decide what information should be kept or not. Database keeps only data needed for all its parts to run healthy.

Just had an idea, that is you have transaction log archive (which I really doubt), then you can re-run them on a back up of a database and may be they (transaction logs) contain timestamp of a row being added or changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky, you have records in other tables that depend on the record you are interested in. These records may have a timestamp when they were created.
So you have at least a ballpark when the record you care about may have been created.
Other than that, the rate at which the primary key usually grows may provide another estimate when your record was created.

But yes, these are just estimates. Other approaches are mentioned in the other existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do so :
https://www.marcus-povey.co.uk/2013/03/11/automatic-create-and-modified-timestamps-in-mysql/

I hope this can help